# Plotting a Bar graph

Tags: r

I have a dataset as follows:
(10,75)
(20,80)
(50,85)
(100,92)

How to plot a bar-graph in R? I saw many examples in the net but none of them conform to this simple circumstance. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
data1=rbind(c(10,20,50,100),c(75,80,85,92))
barplot(data1, beside=TRUE, col=c("blue", "red"))
```

Comment: Thanks CCurtis. If I write `barplot(data,xlab="N",ylab="Trojan Coverage")`, it also shows x and y labels. But the bar has two colors, dark and light. Why so?

Comment: Now, I get it. But this is not what I want. Here (10,20,50,100) is x-axis and (75,80,85,92) is y-axis. What should I do then?

Comment: Its the default to show colors for each group I think. If you want a single color just specify it `barplot(data,xlab="N",ylab="Trojan Coverage", col="grey")`

Comment: As I said, I want not two adjacent bars but just one bar which has x-label as N=50 and y-height as 85. I hope you understand my question.

Comment: `plot(c(10,20,50,100),c(75,80,85,92),type="h")` You can use plot and specify type="h".

Comment: Thanks again, but it makes the x-axis proportional to the actual value, like 100 is as far from 50 as 50 from 0. I want 100 to be next to 50. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: I think you can also do it with `barplot` if you specify `space` if you prefer that.

Comment: Ok so you just want to label the axis. Use `barplot` for that. `barplot(c(75,80,85,92),names.arg=c(10,20,50,100))`

Comment: Good. Try to be a little more specific in future questions so there's less confusion.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, you can always use the `ggplot2` library.  Because of the way the data is shaped, you should also use the `reshape2` library to differentiate between variables.  It's a bit more complicated in this case, but in general you'll get nicer-looking barplots.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
#id variable tells what row number is used
data1=as.data.frame(cbind(id=1:4,var1=c(10,20,50,100),var2=c(75,80,85,92)))
#melt will create a row for each variable of each row, except it saves the id as a separate variable that's on every row
data1=melt(data1,id.vars='id')
#ggplot tells what data set is used and which variables do what
#geom_bar tells what type of plot should be used and certain options for the plot 
ggplot(data1,aes(x=id,y=value,fill=variable))+geom_bar(stat='identity',position='dodge')
```

[image]